# java - Equivalent of Class<?> with Enum

Tags: java, enums

In java, I know you can use `Class<?>`. I was wondering if the same thing is possible with `Enum`s.

I would like to declare something that would look like this:
`HashMap<Enum<?>, Object> myMap = ...`

Comment: At first sight, it looks promising! Thanks!

Comment: Are the keys all going to come from the same enum? If so, use `EnumMap`. If not, what you've written looks right.

Comment: I just saw that all keys need to come from the same enum to use `EnumMap`. In my case, this isn't possible.

Comment: Is your key supposed to be an actual `enum` (e.g. `CLUBS`,`SPADES`,`HEARTS`,`DIAMONDS`) or classes of enums? (e.g. `Suits.class`)?

Comment: My key will be classes of enums and the associated value will be a value of the enum used as key.

Comment: In that case you want a `Map<Class<? extends Enum<?>>, Enum<?>>`

Comment: I'll try this! Thanks!